# CodeIgniter display users from db that are not the admin

Tags: php, codeigniter, display

So I've successfully made the methods in controller so when someone logs in my website and it's the admin ( value 1 in the column admin from db, and the normal users have the value 0), to redirect him to a page who only he can see. Now, I want to display all the users that are not the admin, for the admin, but I don't know how to make it work honestly.

Model:

```
 public function display_users() {

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, fname, email, username, password FROM register WHERE admin = 0');
    return $query->result();
}
```

also tried this one in the model:

```
  $this->db->select('id', 'fname', 'lname', 'email', 'username', 'password')
           ->where('admin', 0)
           ->get('register')
           ->result_array();
```

Controller:

```
   public function admin() {

    $isLogged = $this->session->userdata('email');

    if ($isLogged) {
        $check_admin = $this->signup_model->admin();

        if ($check_admin == 1) {
            $this->signup_model->display_users();

            $this->load->view('navbar');
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('admin');
            $this->load->view('footer');
        } else {
            redirect('users/login');
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<table class="usersTable">
<thead>
    <tr class="column">
        <th class="cell">ID</th>
        <th class="cell">First Name</th>
        <th class="cell">Last Name</th>
        <th class="cell">Email</th>
        <th class="cell">Username</th>
        <th class="cell">Password</th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
     <?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) { 

        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $row->id; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $row->fname; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $row->lname; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $row->email; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $row->username; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $row->password; ?> </td>


    </tr>
    <?php }} ?>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use DB functions in your view. You need to set a variable in your controller and send it to your view, something like this :

Model

```
public function display_users() {

    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id, fname, email, username, password FROM register WHERE admin = 0');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

Controller

```
public function admin() {
    $return = array();
    $isLogged = $this->session->userdata('email');

    if ($isLogged) {
        $check_admin = $this->signup_model->admin();

        if ($check_admin == 1) {
            $return['users'] = $this->signup_model->display_users();

            $this->load->view('navbar');
            $this->load->view('header');
            $this->load->view('admin', $return);
            $this->load->view('footer');
        } else {
            redirect('users/login');
        }
    }
}
```

View :

```
<table class="usersTable">
<thead>
    <tr class="column">
        <th class="cell">ID</th>
        <th class="cell">First Name</th>
        <th class="cell">Last Name</th>
        <th class="cell">Email</th>
        <th class="cell">Username</th>
        <th class="cell">Password</th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
     <?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $user['id']; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $user['fname']; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $user['lname']; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $user['email']; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $user['username']; ?> </td>
        <td class="cell"><?php echo $user['password']; ?> </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: views/admin.php

Line Number: 17

Comment: Yep, I'm updating my answer, the query in the model was wrong, it should use `result_array()` instead of `result()`.

Comment: Thank you a lot!!! It works now, I get an error at showing lname, but the rest work, I'll figure it out, thanks again for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Get the role id of logged in user in some variable like $roleId

if($roleId == 1)   // Visible only for admin
{
    $resultSet = $this->db->query("SELECT id, fname, email, username, password FROM register WHERE role != '1'");
    // It will give you the user list other than admin role.
    return $resultSet;
}
```

Controller:

if ($check_admin == 1) {
            $result = $this->signup_model->display_users();

```
        // pass this variable on the view so that you can use it there.

        $this->load->view('navbar');
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('admin', $result);   // like that
        $this->load->view('footer');
    } else {
        redirect('users/login');
    }
```

Comment: I still get errors because of my view: 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object,    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result